# I have over 2GB of internal memory and can't install or update some apps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, installation, insufficient-memory, cyanogenmod

I tried to search for some answer but couldn't find anything.

I'm using cyanogenmod-11 on a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini.

I am pretty sure I have enough space on the internal memory, but I still receive the insufficient space message when trying to update and/or install some apps, but not all of them.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Probably the `/cache` partition was full.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `fix permissions` entry in your custom recovery menu. In most cases this fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up reinstalling the entire opperating system and that solved the problem.

Comment: If it happens again, then try this: open the stock dialer (stock phone app); enter *#9900#; from the menu that appears (usually instantaneously, but sometimes it takes a few seconds) choose “Delete dumpstate/logcat" and then try to install or update your apps.